# Wildfly 20 - Admin ManagementRealm (security-realm) on ldap SSL

Tags: ldap, realm, wildfly

I configure a wildfly 20 and i have a problem with the ManagementRealm (security-realm) on ldap SSL.
With LDAP, it's OK, but as soon as i switch to ldap**s** the authentication no longer works.
The login window opens and whatever account I indicate (even a true or false login) I turn back to the "Connect to Management Interface" screen (practically blank).

And I have no errors in any log.
I tried a WildFly 19 and 20, on centos 8.
The trustore does exist, I added it in the startup variable (as well as its password)
Here is an excerpt from my standalone.xml file

```
<security-realms>
    <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
        <authentication>
            <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
            <ldap connection="ldap_connection" base-dn="OU=Utilisateurs,DC=org">
                <advanced-filter filter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=APP-ADMIN,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=org))"/>
            </ldap>
            <truststore path="truststore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="XXX" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
            <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
        </authorization>
    </security-realm>
    <security-realm name="LdapSSLRealm">
        <authentication>
            <truststore path="truststore.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="XXX" />
        </authentication>
    </security-realm>
</security-realms>
<outbound-connections>
    <ldap name="ldap_connection" url="ldaps://serveurad:636" search-dn="user" search-credential="XXX"/>
</outbound-connections>
```

If anyone has an idea I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I believe you have to also reference the security realm (containing the ref to the trust store) in your `<outbound-connection />`:

```
<outbound-connections>
    <ldap name="ldap_connection" url="ldaps://serveurad:636" search-dn="user" search-credential="XXX" security-realm="LdapSSLRealm"/>
</outbound-connections>
```